# How to swap buttons (with jQuery) based on radio button checked or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a UI that the user will choose a shipping address. The design is essentially using a radio button pattern, where the checked "card" would be green and a button would change based on the card (radio button) being checked.

Basically, there is a default button with a primary class and it says "Deliver to this Address", but when the card gets checked, it should change to "Selected Address". This is now working. I first tried to use the "same" button but change the inside text or html, and classes, but that didn't work out too well. So, now I thought to show and hide buttons based on the radio button checked state.

But, I am having a hard time with siblings, parents, children, etc. - traversing the DOM to get the effect I want. What I want is only the checked card shows green with the "Selected Address" button. This should even be on page load if one of the cards is checked. And, the moment I check another card, to "uncheck" all other cards and revert that button back to the "Deliver to this Address" button.

I've made a JS Fiddle to show what I mean fully: https://jsfiddle.net/gamehendgeVA/b98v65tx/3/

Here is the JS I was trying:

```
 jQuery(".selectedAddressButton").hide();

  jQuery(function () {
     jQuery(".addressRadio").change(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
        jQuery(this).siblings().find(".selectedAddressButton").show();
        jQuery(this).siblings().find(".deliverButton").hide();
    } else {
        jQuery(this).siblings().find(".selectedAddressButton").hide();
        jQuery(this).parents().find(".deliverButton").show();
    }
 });
});
```

(I had to use "jQuery" in the place of `$` to get things to work due to some strange work files, not exactly sure why.)

And a snippet of one of the radio button `"cards"`:

```
<label class="fullWidth">
        <input type="radio" name="selectAddress" class="card-input-element d-none hideOffScreen addressRadio" id="address1" value="address1">
        <div class="card card-body bg-light d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center radioCard">
            <div class="addressField">John Doe</div>
            <div class="addressField">123 Anytown St.</div>
            <div class="addressField">Springfield, MD 22365</div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
                    <div class="deliverButton" style="margin-top:12px;">
                        <div type="button" class="btn btn-primary-custom" style="margin-right:10px;">Deliver to this Address</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="selectedAddressButton" style="margin-top:12px;">
                        <div style="margin-top:12px;">
                            <div type="button" class="btn btn-success-custom" style="margin-right:10px;"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right:6px;"></i>Selected Address</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-left =" style="margin-top:15px;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary-custom" style="margin-right:10px;">Edit</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary-custom">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</label>
```

I thought to turn to the experts to see if I'm on the right path - maybe there's a simpler way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Any help is gratefully appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet below acts as you wish.

I've written an extra few lines of CSS and used jquery to add a `.selected` class to the surrounding label. If also unselects previously selected cards, and can be used with multiple radio groups on a single page.

The jquery has been fully commented below.

Let me know if you wanted something else.

### New CSS

```
label .selectedAddressButton, label.selected .deliverButton {
  display: none;
}

label.selected .selectedAddressButton, label .deliverButton {
  display: inherit;
}
```

---

## Demo

```js
// Add change event for you radio button class
$(".addressRadio").change(function() {

  // Check the radio button group name
  // So you can have multiple radio groups on a single page
  radioGroup = $(this).attr("name");

  // Cycle through each of the associated radio buttons
  $("input[type='radio'][name='" + radioGroup + "']").each(function() {
  
    // Remove any selected classes from the wrapping label
    $(this).closest("label").removeClass("selected");

  });

  // Check if the changed radio button has been selected 
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

    // Add the selected class if it has
    $(this).closest("label").addClass("selected");

  }

});
```

```css
label.fullWidth {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.card-input-element+.card {
  /*height: calc(36px + 2*1rem);*/
  color: #005499;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.card-input-element+.card:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 2px solid #005499;
}

.card-input-element:checked+.card {
  border: 2px solid #c3e6cb;
  background-color: #d4edda;
  -webkit-transition: border .3s;
  -o-transition: border .3s;
  transition: border .3s;
  content: '\f00c';
  color: #0e6d2e;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 24px;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInCheckbox;
  animation-name: fadeInCheckbox;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.card-input-element:checked+.card::after {
  content: '\f00c';
  color: #0e6d2e;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 24px;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInCheckbox;
  animation-name: fadeInCheckbox;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 5px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInCheckbox {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-20deg);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInCheckbox {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateZ(-20deg);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}

.addressField {
  font-family: Lato, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.radioCard {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 6px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.radioCard:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* note: the position relative goes with the position absolute on the ::after to get the checkmark in the top-right of the div */


/* hiding actual radio button away from screen */

input[type="checkbox"].hideOffScreen,
input[type="radio"].hideOffScreen {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
}

.btn-success-custom {
  font-family: "ProximaNova", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #28a745;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  min-height: 38px;
  transition: background 0.5s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.5s ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: background 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.btn-success-custom:hover,
.btn-success-custom:focus,
.btn-success-custom:active,
.btn-success-custom.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-success-custom {
  background-color: #218838;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-success-custom:active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-success-custom {
  background-image: none;
}

label .selectedAddressButton,
label.selected .deliverButton {
  display: none;
}

label.selected .selectedAddressButton,
label .deliverButton {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div>Is the address you'd like to use displayed below? If so, select the corresponding box below. Or, you can <a>enter a different address</a>.</div>
    <div class="radioPanel">
      <label class="fullWidth">
<input type="radio" name="selectAddress" class="card-input-element d-none hideOffScreen addressRadio" id="address1" value="address1">
<div class="card card-body bg-light d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center radioCard">
<div class="addressField">John Doe</div>
<div class="addressField">123 Anytown St.</div>
<div class="addressField">Springfield, MD 22365</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 text-left">
<div class="deliverButton" style="margin-top:12px;">
<div type="button" class="btn btn-primary-custom" style="margin-right:10px;">Deliver to this Address</div>
</div>
<div class="selectedAddressButton" style="margin-top:12px;">
<div style="margin-top:12px;"><div type="button" class="btn btn-success-custom" style="margin-right:10px;"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right:6px;"></i>Selected Address</div></div>
</div> 
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 text-left =" style="margin-top:15px;">  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary-custom" style="margin-right:10px;">Edit</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary-custom">Delete</button>   
</div>
</div>
</div>
</label>
      <label class="fullWidth" style="margin-top:10px;">
<input type="radio" name="selectAddress" class="card-input-element d-none hideOffScreen addressRadio" id="address2" value="address2">
<div class="card card-body bg-light d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center radioCard">
<div class="addressField">Sally Smith</div>
<div class="addressField">555 Elm St.</div>
<div class="addressField">Nantucket, CA 55698</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 text-left">
<div class="deliverButton" style="margin-top:12px;">
<div type="button" class="btn btn-primary-custom" style="margin-right:10px;">Deliver to this Address</div>
</div>
<div class="selectedAddressButton" style="margin-top:12px;">
<div style="margin-top:12px;"><div type="button" class="btn btn-success-custom" style="margin-right:10px;"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right:6px;"></i>Selected Address</div></div>
</div> 
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 text-left =" style="margin-top:15px;">  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary-custom" style="margin-right:10px;">Edit</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary-custom">Delete</button>   
</div>
</div>
</div>
</label>
    </div>
    <!-- /.radioPanel -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! You got it. I tried the others who posted (thanks to them also), but no luck. You knew exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks so much for helping (and teaching) me!! :)

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is good. Just wanted to add some variation/alternative that achieves the same result, with less code and more straightforward approaches:

Add/remove a `selected` class on the parent of the `.addressRadio` element corresponding to the `:checked` state of this radio button.

```
$('.addressRadio').change(function() {
  $(this)
    .closest('label.fullWidth')
    .toggleClass('selected', this.checked);

  $('.addressRadio')
    .not(this)
    .closest('label.fullWidth.selected')
    .removeClass('selected');
});
```

Or even simpler, with a custom plugin (see the implementation of `.toggleClassUnique()` on the demo code down below). May not be particularly useful unless you need reusable functionality across your application, but here it is anyway:

```
$('.addressRadio').change(function() {
  $(this)
    .closest('label.fullWidth')
    .toggleClassUnique('selected', this.checked);
});
```

So, this additional class will then be used to determine if its "target" chilren (`.selectedAddressButton` and `.deliverButton`) are to hide or show.

#### CSS

```css
.fullWidth .selectedAddressButton {
  display: none;
}

.fullWidth.selected .selectedAddressButton {
  display: block;
}

.fullWidth.selected .deliverButton {
  display: none;
}
```

This also sets the initial visibility of `.selectedAddressButton` to be "hidden", or technically `display: none`, thus you should not need Javascript for this.

---

Last but not least, have a look at [`jQuery.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) for a potential fix for your jQuery aliasing issue.

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using $. If you need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back to the other library with a call to `$.noConflict()`. Old references of $ are saved during jQuery initialization; `noConflict()` simply restores them.

Or simply pass in a reference to the global jQuery object within a function scope:

```
(function ($) {

  $(function() {
    // More code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });

})(jQuery);
```

You would typically add that to the very top of your JS file, and all codes that require jQuery should then go inside this wrapper.

---

#### Full working demo

```js
(function($) {

  $('.addressRadio').change(function() {
    $(this)
      .closest('label.fullWidth')
      .toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
      
    $('.addressRadio')
      .not(this)
      .closest('label.fullWidth.selected')
      .removeClass('selected');
  });
  
})(window.jQuery);
```

```css
.fullWidth .selectedAddressButton {
  display: none;
}

.fullWidth.selected .selectedAddressButton {
  display: block;
}

.fullWidth.selected .deliverButton {
  display: none;
}

label.fullWidth {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.card-input-element+.card {
  /*height: calc(36px + 2*1rem);*/
  color: #005499;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.card-input-element+.card:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 2px solid #005499;
}

.card-input-element:checked+.card {
  border: 2px solid #c3e6cb;
  background-color: #d4edda;
  -webkit-transition: border .3s;
  -o-transition: border .3s;
  transition: border .3s;
  content: '\f00c';
  color: #0e6d2e;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 24px;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInCheckbox;
  animation-name: fadeInCheckbox;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.card-input-element:checked+.card::after {
  content: '\f00c';
  color: #0e6d2e;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 24px;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInCheckbox;
  animation-name: fadeInCheckbox;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 5px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInCheckbox {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-20deg);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInCheckbox {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateZ(-20deg);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}

.addressField {
  font-family: Lato, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.radioCard {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 6px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.radioCard:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* note: the position relative goes with the position absolute on the ::after to get the checkmark in the top-right of the div */


/* hiding actual radio button away from screen */

input[type="checkbox"].hideOffScreen,
input[type="radio"].hideOffScreen {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
}

.btn-success-custom {
  font-family: "ProximaNova", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #28a745;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  min-height: 38px;
  transition: background 0.5s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.5s ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: background 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.btn-success-custom:hover,
.btn-success-custom:focus,
.btn-success-custom:active,
.btn-success-custom.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-success-custom {
  background-color: #218838;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-success-custom:active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-success-custom {
  background-image: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <div>Is the address you'd like to use displayed below? If so, select the corresponding box below. Or, you can <a>enter a different address</a>.</div>
      <div class="radioPanel">
         <label class="fullWidth">
            <input type="radio" name="selectAddress" class="card-input-element d-none hideOffScreen addressRadio" id="address1" value="address1">
            <div class="card card-body bg-light d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center radioCard">
               <div class="addressField">John Doe</div>
               <div class="addressField">123 Anytown St.</div>
               <div class="addressField">Springfield, MD 22365</div>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
                     <div class="deliverButton" style="margin-top:12px;">
                        <div type="button" class="btn btn-primary-custom" style="margin-right:10px;">Deliver to this Address</div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="selectedAddressButton" style="margin-top:12px;">
                        <div style="margin-top:12px;">
                           <div type="button" class="btn btn-success-custom" style="margin-right:10px;"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right:6px;"></i>Selected Address</div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 text-left =" style="margin-top:15px;">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary-custom" style="margin-right:10px;">Edit</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary-custom">Delete</button>   
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </label>
         <label class="fullWidth" style="margin-top:10px;">
            <input type="radio" name="selectAddress" class="card-input-element d-none hideOffScreen addressRadio" id="address2" value="address2">
            <div class="card card-body bg-light d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center radioCard">
               <div class="addressField">Sally Smith</div>
               <div class="addressField">555 Elm St.</div>
               <div class="addressField">Nantucket, CA 55698</div>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
                     <div class="deliverButton" style="margin-top:12px;">
                        <div type="button" class="btn btn-primary-custom" style="margin-right:10px;">Deliver to this Address</div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="selectedAddressButton" style="margin-top:12px;">
                        <div style="margin-top:12px;">
                           <div type="button" class="btn btn-success-custom" style="margin-right:10px;"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right:6px;"></i>Selected Address</div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 text-left =" style="margin-top:15px;">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary-custom" style="margin-right:10px;">Edit</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary-custom">Delete</button>   
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </label>
      </div>
      <!-- /.radioPanel -->
   </div>
</div>
```

#### With custom jQuery plugin

```js
(function($) {

  $('.addressRadio').change(function() {
    $(this)
      .closest('label.fullWidth')
      .toggleClassUnique('selected', this.checked);
  });
  
  
  // Custom plugin
  $.fn.toggleClassUnique = function (className, state) {
    this
      .toggleClass(className, state)
      .siblings()
      .removeClass(className);
      
    return this;
  };
  
})(window.jQuery);
```

```css
.fullWidth .selectedAddressButton {
  display: none;
}

.fullWidth.selected .selectedAddressButton {
  display: block;
}

.fullWidth.selected .deliverButton {
  display: none;
}

label.fullWidth {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.card-input-element+.card {
  /*height: calc(36px + 2*1rem);*/
  color: #005499;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.card-input-element+.card:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 2px solid #005499;
}

.card-input-element:checked+.card {
  border: 2px solid #c3e6cb;
  background-color: #d4edda;
  -webkit-transition: border .3s;
  -o-transition: border .3s;
  transition: border .3s;
  content: '\f00c';
  color: #0e6d2e;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 24px;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInCheckbox;
  animation-name: fadeInCheckbox;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.card-input-element:checked+.card::after {
  content: '\f00c';
  color: #0e6d2e;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 24px;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInCheckbox;
  animation-name: fadeInCheckbox;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 5px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInCheckbox {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-20deg);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInCheckbox {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateZ(-20deg);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
}

.addressField {
  font-family: Lato, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.radioCard {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 6px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.radioCard:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* note: the position relative goes with the position absolute on the ::after to get the checkmark in the top-right of the div */


/* hiding actual radio button away from screen */

input[type="checkbox"].hideOffScreen,
input[type="radio"].hideOffScreen {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
}

.btn-success-custom {
  font-family: "ProximaNova", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #28a745;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  min-height: 38px;
  transition: background 0.5s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.5s ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: background 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.btn-success-custom:hover,
.btn-success-custom:focus,
.btn-success-custom:active,
.btn-success-custom.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-success-custom {
  background-color: #218838;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-success-custom:active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-success-custom {
  background-image: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <div>Is the address you'd like to use displayed below? If so, select the corresponding box below. Or, you can <a>enter a different address</a>.</div>
      <div class="radioPanel">
         <label class="fullWidth">
            <input type="radio" name="selectAddress" class="card-input-element d-none hideOffScreen addressRadio" id="address1" value="address1">
            <div class="card card-body bg-light d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center radioCard">
               <div class="addressField">John Doe</div>
               <div class="addressField">123 Anytown St.</div>
               <div class="addressField">Springfield, MD 22365</div>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
                     <div class="deliverButton" style="margin-top:12px;">
                        <div type="button" class="btn btn-primary-custom" style="margin-right:10px;">Deliver to this Address</div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="selectedAddressButton" style="margin-top:12px;">
                        <div style="margin-top:12px;">
                           <div type="button" class="btn btn-success-custom" style="margin-right:10px;"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right:6px;"></i>Selected Address</div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 text-left =" style="margin-top:15px;">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary-custom" style="margin-right:10px;">Edit</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary-custom">Delete</button>   
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </label>
         <label class="fullWidth" style="margin-top:10px;">
            <input type="radio" name="selectAddress" class="card-input-element d-none hideOffScreen addressRadio" id="address2" value="address2">
            <div class="card card-body bg-light d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center radioCard">
               <div class="addressField">Sally Smith</div>
               <div class="addressField">555 Elm St.</div>
               <div class="addressField">Nantucket, CA 55698</div>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
                     <div class="deliverButton" style="margin-top:12px;">
                        <div type="button" class="btn btn-primary-custom" style="margin-right:10px;">Deliver to this Address</div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="selectedAddressButton" style="margin-top:12px;">
                        <div style="margin-top:12px;">
                           <div type="button" class="btn btn-success-custom" style="margin-right:10px;"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right:6px;"></i>Selected Address</div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 text-left =" style="margin-top:15px;">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary-custom" style="margin-right:10px;">Edit</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary-custom">Delete</button>   
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </label>
      </div>
      <!-- /.radioPanel -->
   </div>
</div>
```

P.S. If you're interested in creating your own, see [how to create a basic plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).

Answer (score 0):

One way to simplify it would be to use the "toggle" method.

```
jQuery(".selectedAddressButton").hide();

jQuery(function () {
    jQuery(".addressRadio").change(function() {   
        jQuery(this).siblings().find(".selectedAddressButton").toggle();
        jQuery(this).siblings().find(".deliverButton").toggle();
    }
});
```

Toggling doesn't require you to know the previous state.  This way you don't even need to know if the checkbox was checked.

Answer (score 0):

You should set default view when any checkbox is checked, Try below code:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery(".addressRadio").change(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
            jQuery(document).find(".selectedAddressButton").hide(); // To hide all select buttons
            jQuery(document).find(".deliverButton").show(); //To show all deliver button                 
            jQuery(this).siblings().find(".selectedAddressButton").show();
            jQuery(this).siblings().find(".deliverButton").hide();
        } else {
            jQuery(this).siblings().find(".selectedAddressButton").hide();
            jQuery(this).parents().find(".deliverButton").show();
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps you.